# Query rows based on previous rows

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table with some financial price data in it. This data has a type (one of 'T', 'B', or 'S'), a timestamp, and a price. I need to find the rows of type 'T' whose prices are either below the price of the previous 'B'-type row or above the price of the previous 'S'-type row.

Here is some example data:

```
+-------+------+----------------------------------+---------------+
| id    | type | htime                            | price         |
+-------+------+----------------------------------+---------------+
|  4505 | T    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.585891       | 5799.30000000 |
|  4506 | B    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.585891       | 5799.00000000 |
|  4507 | S    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.586754       | 5801.40000000 |
|  4508 | S    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.586802       | 5801.10000000 |
|  4509 | B    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.586818       | 5799.30000000 |
|  4510 | T    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.586820       | 5799.30000000 |
|  4511 | T    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.586820       | 5799.00000000 |
|  4512 | B    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.586820       | 5799.00000000 |
|  4515 | S    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.587087       | 5801.10000000 |
|  4516 | S    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.588252       | 5801.10000000 |
|  4591 | S    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.639867       | 5801.10000000 |
|  4608 | T    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.657640       | 5798.00000000 |
|  4609 | B    | 2022-04-24 19:41:00.657640       | 5797.20000000 |
+-------+------+----------------------------------+---------------+
```

So here I would like to have the query return rows with id 4511 (type = 'T' and price is less than price of the previous row with type = 'B') and 4608 (same reason). I don't want row 4510, because its price is neither less than the previous 'B' row nor above the previous 'S' row. I probably just want to ignore row 4505, but it's not important to me what happens there.

I have tried the following query:

```
WITH bids AS (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE type = 'B'),
     offers AS (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE type = 'S')
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE type = 'T') trades
WHERE trades.price < (SELECT price FROM bids WHERE bids.htime < trades.htime ORDER BY htime DESC LIMIT 1)
   OR trades.price > (SELECT price FROM offers WHERE offers.htime < trades.htime ORDER BY htime DESC LIMIT 1);
```

but it's extremely slow. I'm hoping there's an easier self-join type solution, but I'm pretty new at this.

There is an index on the table on (type, htime).

I am using MariaDB 10.5.13

Comment: Hello, I saw you marked my answer as correct and then removed it, doesn't my query fetch the expected result? If it needs some correction you can tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to SO!

Try this query, theoretically, it shouldn't be slower.

The idea in this solution is to add an extra result in the select clause, that will be generated using a subquery, the result of which will either be null if the criteria are not met or the id of the previous row that meets the criteria.

Finally you can wrap this to an extra select just to present the rows that actually meet the criteria.

```
select results.id, results.previousId from (
    select t1.*, (select t2.id from test22 t2 
    where t1.type = 'T' 
    and ((t2.type='B' and t1.price<t2.price) or (t2.type='S' and t1.price>t2.price)) 
    and t2.htime<t1.htime order by t2.htime asc limit 1) as previousId
    from test22 as t1) 
as results 
where results.previousId is not null;
```